# How to label the first occurrence of a value in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I know using match() will extract the first occurrence of a variable, but how can I create a new column labeling the first occurrence?

for example how could I get:

```
example <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,3,4), label = c(1,0,0,1,1,1))
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option with `duplicated` in `base R`

```
example$label <- +(!duplicated(example$id))
```

-output

```
example
#  id label
#1  1     1
#2  1     0
#3  1     0
#4  2     1
#5  3     1
#6  4     1
```

`duplicated` returns a logical column with TRUE for duplicate elements of 'id' and FALSE for non-duplicates i.e. the first occurrence.  Negating (`!`) reverses the TRUE -> FALSE and viceversa, then coerce it to binary with `+` or `as.integer`

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using ´ave`

```
transform(
  example,
  label_new = +(ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along) == 1)
)
```

gives

```
  id label label_new
1  1     1         1
2  1     0         0
3  1     0         0
4  2     1         1
5  3     1         1
6  4     1         1
```